# Tracking new MS Edge processes and its IDs with native Windows 10 tools (e.g. PowerShell 5.1)

Tags: windows, powershell, process, microsoft-edge, native

There are multiple MS Edge windows open.

[image]

My PowerShell script first finds all MS Edge processes and their IDs.
It then opens simple HTML in a new window in WebApp mode using the Start-Process 'msedge' cmdlet, i.e. creates a new MS Edge process that immediately changes its ID to an unknown one to me.

[image]

Ок. I think further that for me it is not a problem. Let's compare the old list of MS Edge processes with the new list and thus find the new process.
Ок. No sooner said than done.

[image]

But then I get another problem. When I close the MS Edge WebApp window, a completely different and random MS Edge process ends.

[image]

How does it work?
How do I track the process of an MS Edge WebApp window using PowerShell 5.1?

Very important: I need to complete the task with built-in Windows 10 tools. I can't use third-party libraries!

Thank you.

Comment: There isn't a 1-to-1 relationship because Edge (and other Chromium-based browsers for that matter) use multiple processes, some shared, for different responsibilities - separate processes for rendering different tab groups, a separate processes for interfacing with your GPU for, a separate process for handling crashing tabs, etc. If you want to get the Process ID of the process you kicked off with `Start-Process`, use `$process = Start-Process msedge -PassThru; $process.Id`. Use `Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'msedge.exe'" |Select Name,ProcessId,CommandLine` to see the cmd line

Answer (score 0):

- As Mathias points out, there is no one-to-one relationship between *tabs* (or even *windows*) on the one hand and `msedge` *processes* on the other.
- Additionally, when you use `msedge.exe` to launch a new tab, a *transient* process is typically used that delegates to a *preexisting* `msedge` process and then exits; therefore:

  - Using the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)' `-PassThru` switch to obtain the *directly* launched process will *not* help you.
  - Similarly, examining the *command lines* that were used to launch the running `msedge` processes does *not* reflect the URLs of the open tabs.
- In fact, **it seems that a *single* process is responsible for managing *all* open Edge windows**, including those opened in web-application mode via the `--app=<url>` or `--new-window` CLI parameters, and, as of Microsoft Edge v115, that process' command line is:

  ```bash
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --no-startup-window /prefetch:5
  ```
- Additionally, what this process reports in the `.MainWindowTitle` property of the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instances that [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) outputs (ultimately retrieved via the [`GetWindowText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw) WinAP function), corresponds to the title of the *active tab* in *whatever window was most recently active*, and even that tab's title itself changes based on what page it currently shows - see the bottom section for details.

---

It follows from the above:

- You cannot identify a *process* that *exclusively* manages your web-application window, because no such process exists.
- From what I can tell, **the best you can do is to find your web application's *window***, as shown below, but note that this **will work *if and only if***:

  - You know the *title* of your web-application window,
  - *and* there are no *other* windows with the same title,
  - *and* the user hasn't navigated *to a different page*, because that *changes the title*.
  - Additionally, note that the name of the relevant window class, `Chrome_WidgetWin_1`, is shared with other Chromium-based browsers, so that a *Chrome* web-application window would be found this way too.

The following finds the web-application window with title `Google`, as of Microsoft Edge v115 (the *Chromium*-based implementation):

```bash
# The full window title of your Edge-based web-application window (case doesn't matter).
$windowTitle = 'Google'

# Use a P/Invoke call to find the window by class name and title,
# and returns its hWnd (window handle).
$hWndWebApp = 
  (Add-Type -NameSpace NS$PID -Name WindowHelper -PassThru  @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
'@)::FindWindow('Chrome_WidgetWin_1', $windowTitle)

# Display the result:
if (0 -eq $hWndWebApp) {
  Write-Warning ('No Edge-based web application window with current window title "{0}" found.' -f $windowTitle)
} else {
  'Edge-based web application window with window title "{0}" has hWnd 0x{1:x}' -f $windowTitle, $hWndWebApp
}
```

---

###### Optional reading: How the window-managing Edge process reports its *main* window title:

- The single process that manages all open Edge windows reports its *main* window title *dynamically*:

  - It is the *active* tab in the *currently or most recently active window*, across all windows (if applicable) that determines the title.
  - The title is based on that tab's title, which is itself dynamic in reflects the title of whatever page is currently being shown.
- This main window title is reflected in the `.MainWindowTitle` property of the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instances that [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) outputs, and is ultimately retrieved via the [`GetWindowText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw) WinAP function.
- The actual *window title* from the system's perspective i.e. the (here effectively *hidden*) title-bar text of the *window object*, can *differ* from the *tab* title shown to the user in the Edge GUI, in that it may have a *dynamic suffix*, constructed as follows (as of Microsoft Edge v115, expressed using [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) escape sequences):

  - In a separate window opened via an `--app=<url>` CLI argument, *no* suffix is appended, and a regular title bar is shown.
  - In a regular, potentially multi-tab window:

    - If a window has only *one* tab:

      ```bash
       "$visibleTabTitle - $profileName - Microsoft`u{200b}Edge"
      ```
    - If a window has *multiple* tabs:

      - 2 tabs:

        ```bash
        "$visibleTabTitle and 1 more page - $profileName - Microsoft`u{200b}Edge"
        ```
      - 3 or more tabs:

        ```bash
        "$visibleTabTitle and $n more pages - $profileName - Microsoft`u{200b}Edge"
        ```
      - `$visibleTabTitle` and `$profileNames` are placeholders for the tab title as shown to the user and the name of Edge profile, respectively; `$n` represents the number of *additional* tabs.
      - Note the curious use of the ZERO WIDTH SPACE, [`U+200B`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b)) character between the words `Microsoft` and `Edge`.